# How to redir subfolders to different domain than root domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

IHi, I'm to this, I've read and tried all tips I've found here, but it's still not working the way I need.

I'm using htaccess to redir domain and it's structure to new domain:

```
`rewritecond %{http_host} ^www.olddomain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]`
```

It redirs all subfolders e.g. www.olddomain.com/contact/ to www.newdomain.com/contact/ etc., so far so good, BUT I need to redir the mainpage, the one page only, to different URL: 
from www.olddomain.com to www.newdomain.com/about-old/

All I've tried this:

```
`Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^www.olddomain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/about-old/ [r=301,nc,L]
rewritecond %{http_host} ^www.olddomain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]`
```

but it just redirs EVERYTHING to www.newdomain.com/about-old/

Any ideas, please?
Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match home page pattern you need is:

```
^/?$
```

So your full code will be:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

rewritecond %{http_host} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [nc]
rewriterule ^/?$ http://www.newdomain.com/about-old/ [R=301,L]

rewritecond %{http_host} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [nc]
rewriterule ^(.+)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm!

I'll just have to deal with www and non-www version now.

Comment: I tried yesterday, but vote up requires reputation 15, I have only 1, so I'm unable do that, sorry :/

Comment: I'm finally at PC so I did it. (it's not possible tick it on the phone).